# how to convert a JSON data into map in Flutter?

Tags: string, firebase, flutter, dictionary, push-notification

my JSON data is like this:

```
{
notification:{
     title: flutter fcm, 
     body: i got a firebase notification
              }, 
 data:{
     myKey: myValue
      }
}
```

how should I convert it into a map??

This is the value printed on `onMessage()` callback of firebase push notification. It is printing on my console. I want to convert this to map. This JSON data's runtimeType is String.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `dart:convert` package and the `json.decode` method to convert a `JSON` `String` to a `Map`:

```
import 'dart:convert';

final Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(jsonData);
```